# Equivalence of two definitions of $H^{1/2}$: via a double integral and Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, sobolev-spaces

A function $f: S^1\to S^1$ is of class $H^{1/2}(S^1,S^1)$, when 
$$\int\limits_{S^1} \int \limits_{S^1} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|^2}{|x-y|^2} dS(x)dS(y)< \infty$$

but why is that equivalent to 
$$\sum\limits_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}|j| |a_j|^2<\infty$$
where $a_j$ are the Fourier coefficients of $f$?

Comment: Oh, sorry yes, just a typo. I corrected it

Comment: Have you tried using Plancherel's theorem on the first expression?

Comment: It is enough to show that $$\iint_{S^1\times S^1}\left|\frac{e^{nix}-e^{niy}}{x-y}\right|^2\,d\mu$$ behaves like $|n|$ for large $n$s. For such a purpose, one may employ Laplace's method or other techniques, like separating the cases in which $x$ and $y$ are close from the cases in which $x$ and $y$ are fairly distant.